# Is there any way to view history of purchased consumable In-app purchases on iOS?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I know about restoring non-consumable in-app purchases using StoreKit, but I need to get a list of all previous *consumable* purchases of a user. I have an app where consumable purchases stopped working. Normally, I was keeping track of all the consumables with a receipt on my server, which normally happens to be the right way to do. However, I had a major server outage today for a few hours, and any In-app purchases purchased during this period failed to validate with server. From a user's pespective, they've paid for my service, but they didn't get the service, which is the last thing that I want to see. I want to implement a way to restore consumables, either using the StokeKit API in iOS client-side, or getting a list of purchases at the server side from Apple's APIs (if there are any).

What is the preferred way to handle "restoring past consumables of a user"?

Comment: `restoring ... consumables` is against the idea of consumables.

Comment: yes, `restore` may be a bad word choice. let's say `view history of purchases`, which is ultimately what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Local to the app, it keeps no record?

Comment: it keeps record on the server, but the server failed for a few hours. locally keeping is not a very good idea as one may delete the app, or use a tool like LocaliAPStore to bypass purchasing, and because I don't use the server to validate with Apple, use those IAPs freely.